# How to insert a copy row with some different values into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert a new row into the `claim` table. I have tried many other ways but non of them work. What I have now is

```
 INSERT INTO claimant_type
    SELECT ('3' 
            , col1
            , '18'
            , 'ility'
            , col4
            , col5
            , col6)
    FROM claim
    WHERE col4 = '8'
```

When I execute this script, it said ---- Incorrect syntax near ','. which is '3' or col1.

Comment: @DineshReddy: _"... it said ---- Incorrect syntax near ','. which is '3' or col1."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only obvious problem is the parentheses.  You don't want to put them around a `select` list:

```
INSERT INTO claimant_type
    SELECT '3' 
            , col1
            , '18'
            , 'ility'
            , col4
            , col5
            , col6
    FROM claim
    WHERE col4 = '8';
```

I would also recommend that you explicitly list the columns when using `insert`.